# How to use onItemLongClick to show a context menu?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I tried to get answer here but didn't get any perfect answer.
I am trying to show context menu on `onItemLongClick` but no success as i am using both `onItemClick` and `onItemLongClick`

i am using `onItemClick` to start a new activity but no success on both.

Here is the code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_contacts);  

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    new LoadAllContacts().execute();

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    ListView listView = getListView();

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int postion, long id) {
                registerForContextMenu( view );
                openContextMenu( view ); 
            return true;
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AllContactsActivity.this, editContactActivity.class);    
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == 100)
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.listview_menu, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.editContactMI:
        Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), editContactActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(TAG_ID, cId);
        i.putExtra(TAG_NAME, cName);
        i.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NO, cNumber);
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        cId = null;
        cName = null;
        cNumber = null;
        break;
    case R.id.deleteContactMI :
        new DeleteContact().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.saveContactMI:
        break;
    default:
        cId = null;
        cName = null;
        cNumber = null;
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to do/what is it actually doing?

Comment: I am trying to show a menu on long clicking on a listview item and as well on simple clicking i am trying to start a new activity
but nothing happened on both clicks and applications stucks

Comment: "applications stucks" - if the app crashes, it's helpful if you post the logcat output that contains the stack trace.

Comment: here is the log
[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B26-OtOteOInbzJONFl4bDNfRlU/edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to show context menu on onItemLongClick

To use the context menu system, you do not implement an `OnItemLongClickListener`. Instead, you call `registerForContextMenu()` (e.g., from `onCreate()` of the activity). Simply delete your `OnItemLongClickListener` from your code shown above, and you should have better luck.

Comment: but i am wanting to show menu on long click and on simple click i am wanting to start a new activity 
any solution? :(

Comment: @AkmalRasool: The solution is what I wrote. `OnItemClickListener` is your "simple click". Leave that as you have it. Remove `OnItemLongClickListener` (the one containing the word `Long`).

Comment: then how menu will be appear?

Comment: @AkmalRasool: Call `registerForContextMenu()` from someplace like `onCreate()` of your activity. That, and that alone, enables the context menu.

Comment: I totally agree with @CommonsWare answer

Comment: on just calling registerForContextMenu(), would menu will be appear on clicking long on listview item ?

Comment: yes it would appear.. See this [link](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/)

Comment: oh bundle of thanks @CommonsWare and all of you, problem solved by your solution :) 
will it work on all android version

Comment: @CommonsWare : Hello Sir, What if i want to show context menu on some position based Conditions on Listview's Item ? I totally agreed that no need to write onItemLongClick listner for Context menu but I want to show Context Menu on position based Conditions.I have used item.getMenuInfo() but getting info.position = null, Help will be  appreciated.

Comment: @MDroid: Context menus are not particularly common anymore, replaced by other options (e.g., action modes). If by "position" you mean an adapter position in a `ListView`, there is a recipe for finding that, but I haven't looked at it in years and forget the details. If by "position" you mean something else, then I do not know what you are referring to. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain *exactly* what you are seeking, if you are not finding your answers via searching.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes You got me, "position" mean an adapter position in a ListView.. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cursor c_index = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    detail_id = c_index.getInt(c_index.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_RID));
    registerForContextMenu( parent );
    openContextMenu( parent );
    return true;
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_details:
            //some code
            return true;
        case R.id.action_share:
            //some code
            return true;
        case R.id.action_del:
            //enter code here`
           return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```