# setOnLongClickListener with ListView BUG

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Im seeing a weird behaviour when setting a `setOnLongClickListener` for each row in a ListView. To explain, here is a little background:

My ListView has a custom cell, and when the cell is clicked i want to change the colour of each TextView, so in my `cell_layout.xml` i included:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:textColor="@drawable/cell_textview_colors_black"
```

and `@drawable/cell_textview_colors_black` is a selector with the two items:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
<item android:color="@color/black"/>
```

so that the ListView selected state would propagate to each view's inside the cell... It works like a charm, but the problem is that when i add a `setOnLongClickListener` for each cell view in my `BaseAdapter` subclass, the ListView selected state wont propagate to its child's anymore and the TextView changing colour behaviour stopped working!

Any thoughts?
Newton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should set the onLongClickListener to the ListView and not to each row :)

Comment: its actually setOnItemLongClickListener.. but well thought, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause to check:

Are you using the ContextMenu on the list view? i.e. are you using the method  [registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) in your activity? It might influence on the behavior of the long click on other items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use list context menu, not long click event. There is problem like you [How to use onItemLongClick to show a context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924414/how-to-use-onitemlongclick-to-show-a-context-menu/14924459#14924459)

Try to implement context menu [Custom ListView and context menu. How to get it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972945/custom-listview-and-context-menu-how-to-get-it)